# boostrap star rating is not working when we run the files using IIS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used a jquery star rating in my project which is working when
 we run using xampp-apache. but when I confiure in server , it is not
 running on IIS. it is just showing the rectangles and  stars are not
 displaying. Kindly any one help me on this.Why it is not display if it
 runs on IIS?

```
 please find the codes which i have used

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="star-rating.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="star-rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<form>

    <input id="rating-input" type="number" />

</form>
<hr>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#rating-input').rating({
              min: 0,
              max: 5,
              step: 1,
              size: 'xs',
              showClear: false
           });



        $('#btn-rating-input').on('click', function() {
            $('#rating-input').rating('refresh', {
                showClear:true, 
                disabled:true
            });
        });

        $('#rating-input').on('rating.change', function() {
           // alert($('#rating-input').val());
        });

    });
</script>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are your path for the file correct?

Comment: is your console throwing any error?

Comment: the paths are correct and it is running when we do locally using apache in xampp control. but if confirure in IIS is showing as 5 rectangles only. it is not displaying the star

Comment: is this `star-rating.css` file on your server>?

Comment: paths are correct only. i have found the issue when i checked in the cosole as you suggested. There is a font which is reading from bootstrap.min.css which are not loading in IIS with an extenstion of .woff2. I have added the mime type extenstion in the iis for our website. Thanks for your output.